# Prove or disprove that the derivative of $f$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ uniformly continuous.

Prove or disprove that the derivative of $f$ is bounded.

I think the answer is no but how can I found an explicitly counter example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
f(x)=\frac{\sin\left(e^x\right)}{1+x^2}
$$
The derivative is unbounded:
$$
f'\left(x\right)=\frac{-x\sin\left(e^x\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2} +
e^x\frac{\cos\left(e^x\right)}{1+x^2}
$$
yet the function is uniformly continuous:

Let $\epsilon>0$. We can find a compact set $K=[-a, a]$ for some $a>0$, such that for $x\not\in K$ we have
$$
\left|f(x)\right|<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon
$$
Then, for any $x, y \not\in K$ we have $\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|<\epsilon$. Let $K'=[-2a, 2a]$. Continuous functions are uniformly continuous on compact sets, so there exists $\delta>0$ such that the same inequality holds for $x, y\in K'$. If necessary, adjust $\delta$ so that $\delta<a$. Then, if $\left|x-y\right|<\delta$, it implies that either $x,y\in K'$, or $x, y \not\in K$ (or both). In the first case, we have  $\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|<\epsilon$. In the second, $x,y\not\in K$ and the inequality holds as well. Therefore, $f$ is uniformly continuous.